# Windows community toolkit for WinUI3 desktop app

Tags: desktop-application, winui-3

Does windows community toolkit available for the WinUI3 desktop application? Or it is just available for UWP applications?

Answer (score 0):

WinUI3 is C++ with a C# com wrapper. WinUI2 + UWP is C# only and the community toolkit is fully implemented in C#.

So don't expect it to be useable with WinUI3 soon.

Comment: A WinUI 3 version has been available for over a year. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/windows-community-toolkit-for-project-reunion-0-5/

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using WinUI3 with Windows App SDK, you have access to the Windows Community toolkit. You can download it!

Answer (score 0):

Available for WinUI 3 under this new namespace and package set:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=CommunityToolkit.WinUI

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/windows-community-toolkit-for-project-reunion-0-5/

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows community toolkit for Winui3.
refer this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/windows-community-toolkit-for-project-reunion-0-5/

Answer (score -1):

Currently it looks like there is no support for packaged desktop WinUI 3 projects.

Comment: A WinUI 3 version has been available for over a year. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/windows-community-toolkit-for-project-reunion-0-5/